# Use "and", "or" and "foreach" in an advanced where query in eloquent

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I want to do an advanced search with where, I already have an idea how it should work in SQL, but the problem arises when I must use eloquent, here is an example in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM typocharacteristic
    JOIN caracteristicadoproduto ON caracteristicadoproduto.tipoCaracteristica_id = tipocaracteristica.id
    JOIN ON products caracteristicadoproduto.produtos_id = produtos.id
    WHERE (TipoCaracteristica.labelTipo = "tipo_1" AND
    caracteristicaDoProd..labelValor = "value_1" OR
    productfeature.labelValue = "value_2" OR
    productfeature.labelValue = "value_3") OR
    . . .
    caracteristicaDoProd..labelValor = "value_infinity") OR
    (tipoCaracteristica.labelTipo = "tipo_2" AND
    characteristicadoproduto.labelValor = "value_1") OR
    . . .
    productfeature.labelValor = "value_infinity")
```

The closest result I had at Eloquent:

```
$ products = TipoCaracteristica :: join ('caracteristicaDoProduto', 'caracteristicaDoProduto.tipoCaracteristica_id', '=', 'tipoCaracteristica.id')
                -> join ('products', 'productfeature.products_id', '=', 'products.id')
                -> where (function ($ query) use ($ labelsType, $ labelsValue) {
                    foreach ($ labelsTipo as $ labelTipo) {
                        $ query-> orWhere ('TipoCaracteristica.labelTipo', $ labelTipo);
                        foreach ($ labelsValue as $ labelValue) {
                            $ query-> where ('productfeature.labelValue', $ labelValue, 'or');
                        }
                    }
                }) -> get ();
```

Comment: I don't think your sql even have matching parentheses, or at least you haven't shown the full functioning sql to us.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I did a little test, I noticed that it will not be necessary, only that I don't see how to do this consultation.